# URL Query parameter string "=" converts to "&"

Tags: android, spring, query-string, robospice

In my Android project I'm using Robospice with spring-android. Which works fine for all REST communication. But for the below request query parameter "=" is getting converted to "&". Because of this the request is getting failed.

**Query String:** tags=["keywords:default=hello"]

By checking the logs the request is converted as below for making call by the library.

```
http://XXX/rest/media/search?token=123&tags=%5B%22keywords:default&hello%22%5D
```

here "=" sign is converted to "&" in "keywords:default=hello"

**Request Class**

here tags = String.format("[\"keywords:default=%s\"]", mTag);

```
@Override
public MVMediaSearch loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception
{ 
  String search=""; 
  if(!tags.equals(Constants.EMPTY_DATA)) 
    search="&tags="+tags;
  return   getRestTemplate().getForObject( Constants.BASE_URL+"/media/search?token="+token+search, MVMediaSearch.class ); 
}
```

If I fire the URL in a browser, I'm getting error. And if I change the '&' sign to its corresponding url encoded value in browser, it works fine.

Comment: have you tried to use a urlBuilder?

Comment: i tried but the URL is encoded in the following way which is not correct :  %255B%2522keywords%253Adefault%253DAdult%2522%255D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have the same issue.
For alternative, I use getForObject(java.net.URI, java.lang.Class).

```
URI uri = new URI(Constants.BASE_URL+"/media/search?token="+token+search);
getRestTemplate().getForObject(uri, MVMediaSearch.class );
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject(java.net.URI, java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
URI uri = new URI(
    "http",
    Constants.BASE_URL, 
    "/media/search?token=", 
    token,
    search,
    null);
String request = uri.toASCIIString();
```

take a look at [THIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) and see if you understand (you have to adapt to your code - this is not completely done for you)

Comment: throws java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path: CiBhZHVsdHN3aW0tdW5pdmVyc2FsLWFuZHJvaWRwaG9uZRIOMjAyLjg4LjIzNy4yMTIY4eKp7o4oIg1BZHVsdFN3aW1Bc2lhKIAEMggKAklOEgIxMzgHOAhAAQ

Comment: you have to put http in the beginning (i don't know what is inside your Constants.BASE_URL)

Comment: i think the problem is with spring-android. i tried providing the URL in many ways, no luck

Comment: you are probably right, take a look at this example and how they do the requests:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-springandroid/  
Good luck, sorry for not being more useful!